# I want to return a Exception while my return type is Dto

Tags: java, spring-boot

If I couldn't find a user in my db with given id. I want to return an exception instead of null Dto, how can I do this?

```
public UserDto updateUser(Long id, UserDto userDto) {

    UserDto userDtoNew = null;

    if (userRepository.findById(id).isPresent()) {

        User existingUser = userRepository.findById(id).get();
        existingUser.setPassword(userDto.getPassword());
        existingUser.setUserName(userDto.getUserName());
        userDtoNew = userMapper.toDto(existingUser);

        return userDtoNew;
    }

    return userDtoNew;

}
```

Comment: you mean throw an exception? instead of that second return statement, just put throw new Exception(" no result found");

Comment: Yes definitely. I just want to inform people who are trying to reach a user with this ID that there is no such user with that ID.

Comment: so, what more than that do you need?

Comment: To learn  efficient way to do this in Spring Boot.

Comment: this has nothing to do with whether it's spring-boot or not. if you want to throw an Exception: throw an exception

Comment: You should not be calling database twice `userRepository.findById(id)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a terrible way to use a an `Optional`. Please learn how to properly use it.

```java
return userRepository.findById(id)
 .map(it -> {
    it.setPassword(userDto.getPassword());
    it.setUserName(userDto.getUserName());
  }).map(userMapper::toDto)
  .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No user found for " + id));
```

Something along those lines is how to properly use an `Optional` **and** to throw an exception if nothing is found.

Ideally the thing called inside the `map` function/method is just a oneliner. So instead of having the code block with `{}` you might want to move that to a method to make it more readable.

```java
private User update(User user, UserDto userDto) {
  user.setPassword(userDto.getPassword());
  user.setUserName(userDto.getUserName());
  return user;
}
```

```java
return userRepository.findById(id)
 .map(it -> update(it, userDto))
 .map(userMapper::toDto)
 .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No user found for " + id));
```

Comment: Such a good practice of Optional. Thanks.